# Set a program to open at specific screen location at a certain resolution

Tags: command-line, bash, resolution

I'm writing a python program to open certain programs based on the time I login (I.E. whether I'm in work or not). As such different programs open depending on time and I have to manually arrange their screen position. For example, before 6 I'll have Chrome open on my external monitor at a certain position with a certain resolution. After 6 I'll have it maximised on my laptop screen.

Would I need to append something after `$ chrome` to do this or would another method be used?

Comment: You, sir, are a control freak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wmctrl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) to specify any window geometry and placement.

Then you can put each app launch in a script and launch it : `chrome.sh` instead of just `chrome`.